# Managing XML files in a Visual Studio project (2 instances)

Tags: xml, visual-studio, build, automation

Managing XML files in a Visual Studio project (2 instances)

If I add an XML file to my VS project it at the root level of the project with the source files. But then if I want to test or build I need a copy down in the bin directory. Of course I always end up editing the one at the root level that is in VS and then I go to test and am using a different file (one in the bin directory).

Is there a good way to either point the file being edited to the bin file or to always copy when I go to debug (or some other good solution)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the properties pane when you have the file selected, choose "Always copy" (or whatever it is) for the Copy to Output Directory setting.